# Error when compiling the Python bindings of libtorrent

Tags: android, python, c++, linux, build

I'm currently trying to compile the libtorrent source files with Python bindings for Android. To do this, I have my custom toolchain with a compiled Boost library.

I use the following command to configure the libtorrent installation:

```
./configure --host=$CROSSHOST --prefix=$CROSSHOME --with-boost=$CROSSHOME --with-boost-libdir=$CROSSHOME/lib --enable-static --disable-shared --enable-debug --enable-logging --enable-python-binding
```

The variables are setup as follow:

```
export ANDROIDNDK='/home/martijn/Documenten/android-ndk-r9d'
export SYSROOT=$ANDROIDNDK/platforms/android-14/arch-arm
export PYTHON=/home/martijn/Documenten/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2/hostpython
export PYTHON_CPP_FLAGS="-I/home/martijn/Documenten/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2 -I/home/martijn/Documenten/python-for-android/build/python/Python-2.7.2/Include"

# Custom ARM toolchain
export SYSROOT=$ANDROIDNDK/platforms/android-14/arch-arm
export PATH=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.0-arm-linux-androideabi/bin:$PATH
export CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
export CXX=arm-linux-androideabi-g++
export CROSSHOST=arm-linux-androideabi
export CROSSHOME=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.0-arm-linux-androideabi

# Set ARM v5 architecture with debug flag!
export CFLAGS="-g"
export CXXFLAGS=$CLFAGS
```

Compiling without the --enable-python-binding flag gives no problem and I correctly get a libtorrent.so file. At the end of the compilation, I get the following error:

```
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/martijn/Documenten/android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -shared -lm -L/home/martijn/Documenten/python-for-android/build/openssl/openssl-1.0.1g/ -g -fvisibility=hidden build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/alert.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/error_code.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/module.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/datetime.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/fingerprint.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/entry.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/session.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/torrent_info.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/magnet_uri.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/converters.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/string.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/utility.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/session_settings.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/create_torrent.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/big_number.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/torrent_handle.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/torrent_status.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/version.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/ip_filter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/peer_info.o -L../../src/.libs -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -L. -ltorrent-rasterbar -lboost_system -lboost_python -lssl -lcrypto -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/libtorrent.so -L/usr/local/gcc-4.8.0-arm-linux-androideabi/lib
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
error: command 'arm-linux-androideabi-g++' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error. I think have I my arm-linux-androieabi-g++ command setup correctly but maybe there's a setting that I oversee. Anyone here who can help me?